# WordPress Script not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm designing a website for a school and they use a communicator app to display news. Now on the previous website they had this code just pasted there and it worked. But it displays nothing on the new site?

Script:

```
<script src="http/www.d6communicator.com/school/listings.js.php?school=10930&type=news&max=10&width=1200&color=12196e&lang=af"></script>
```

Comment: We need much more information... Are your having javascript errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its because there is a typo in the script src.

```
http/www.
```

should be

```
http://www.
```

Comment: Cant believe i missed that...well its 2am here in Africa haha Thank you so much!

Comment: Haha. Its only these simple mistakes that drive us crazy sometimes.